# instance failure in dataset for desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am developing desktop application.

When i generates reports, it gives me error: "`Instance Failure`".

When i tries to edit dataset also, it gives me same error.

My connection string is>>

```
Data Source=KAM-224CD25139D\LIBRARY;Initial Catalog=Libary;Integrated Security=True
```

I refered these questions>>

[Instance Failure in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830824/instance-failure-in-asp-net)

[Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801827/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server)

From this i also removed double slash in my constring, but there was same error.

I also dont have any @ sign at the start of my connection string as well as no username and password.

Can any one guid me for this??

Comment: Where is this connection string specified? If in C# code, either use @ at the start of the string or \\ instead of \. If in Xml (which doesn't require \ escaping), your connection seems to be correct; in that case, could hyphen be the issue. Can you try [IP address](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/define-sql-server-network-protocol) instead of the machine name?

Comment: Another option is to [generate connection string from visual studio](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suthish_nair/how-to-generate-or-find-connection-string-from-visual-studio/). Choose 'Use Windows Authentication' in the dialog.